# Counting Monday and Friday from a Date Range

Tags: c#, datetime

How can I get Monday and Friday from a date range (**start** and **end** date)?

Example:

**startdate** - 03/24/2014 
**enddate** - 04/01/2014

Result should be:

**Monday** - 2 
**Friday** - 2

I tried this code:

```
Monday = CountDays(DayOfWeek.Monday, startDate, endDate);
Friday = CountDays(DayOfWeek.Friday, startDate, endDate);
```

---

```
static int CountDays(DayOfWeek day, DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    TimeSpan ts = end - start;                     
    int count = (int)Math.Floor(ts.TotalDays / 7); 
    int remainder = (int)(ts.TotalDays % 7);       
    int sinceLastDay = (int)(end.DayOfWeek - day);   
    if (sinceLastDay < 0) sinceLastDay += 7;         

    if (remainder >= sinceLastDay) count++;

    return count > 0 ? count : 0;
}
```

And this code works!  Is there any other way to simplify this code?

Comment: I don't understand why you think increasing the time range would somehow increase the processing time. You're not iterating over anything.

Comment: is there any other way that i can simplify that code? or is there any best way that i can do that?

Comment: Please explain why there should be two Fridays between 2014-03-24 and 2014-04-01?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is already good enough.

```
static int CountDays(DayOfWeek day, DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    start = start.Date.AddDays((7 + day - start.DayOfWeek) % 7);
    if (end < start)
        return 0;
    else
        return ((int)(end - start).TotalDays) / 7 + 1;
}
```

Comment: i think this code look more understandable than my work.